# Upper shape of Temples

Tags: temple

Why all Temples, Mosques, Churches, Gurudwaras, etc have a structure such that the main area on the ground is broad and on top it is pointed something like '/\'. This upper part varies a bit in shape like rounded or conical according to the religion but they are almost similar and this particular upper part shape is not build for normal houses.

So, my confusion is about this upper part of the temples. Is it just to make them different from normal houses or there is some significance of it for shaping it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, ^ shaped is like pyramid, most of temple use this shape in top.

**Pyramid** is absorb energy, it sign of Peace ,Impressive and consciousness.

So that temple top shared as ^ like **pyramid**.

Here are also benefit and reasons for this shape, Building a temple in the shape of a **pyramid** can increase the occupants' lifespan.

[More benefits are here](http://www.vasthusastra.com/power_pyramid.asp)

Answer (score 1):

1. The upper portion is a typically an excellent representation of a Shikhara/Summit - a highest abode.
2. /\ shape is on the top Sanctum Sanctorum - a way of ensuring there is no floor/higher person who could be placed over it.
3. In Kaliyuga, it allowed one to see the temple's highest point from a far-off distance.